# mapping based on nearest date

Tags: r, join, dplyr, left-join

I'd like to take a list of emails that have an assocaited "owner", and dates, and match them against incoming orders, with dates and values. The matching key is email, but I would like it to match on nearest date, as there are some cases where an email address may have 2 different owners.

reproducible example:

```
require(dplyr)

e <- c("e3r@gmail.com", "e3r@gmail.com", "poi@aol.com", "tyu@gmail.com", "poi@aol.com", "tyu@gmail.com")
d <- c("2017-01-01", "2017-04-05", "2017-04-12", "2017-05-05", "2017-08-05", "2017-12-05")
p <- c("Jeff", "Sam", "Sam", "Jeff", "Matt", "Matt")
df <- data_frame(e, d, p) %>% mutate(d=as.Date(d))

o <- c("e3r@gmail.com", "poi@aol.com", "sdf@gmail.com", "tyu@gmail.com")
d2 <- c("2017-02-02", "2017-04-28", "2017-05-05", "2017-07-01")
a <- c(600.50, 3000, 4999.99, 2050.6)
df2 <- data_frame(o, d2, a) %>% mutate(d2 = as.Date(d2))
```

the first df is the map of email address is owned by `p` person. The `df2` is the orders that came in with those email addresses, and I would like to add a column to `df2` that pins the correct "owner" which is whoever has that email address assigned to them *and* is closest in date.

desired result:

```
> df2
# A tibble: 4 x 3
              o         d2       a       newowner
          <chr>     <date>   <dbl>       <char>
1 e3r@gmail.com 2017-02-02  600.50       "Jeff"
2   poi@aol.com 2017-04-28 3000.00       "Sam"
3 sdf@gmail.com 2017-05-05 4999.99       NA
4 tyu@gmail.com 2017-07-01 2050.60       "Jeff"
```

Currently, it is not a massive issue - out of 70k records of "owned" email addresses, there are only ~86 cases of duplication. However, ownership is changing for the last few months of the year and thus could introduce a lot of duplication if ownership moves around. I'm currently taking the owner from the furthest date, and overwriting the other owners in those 86 examples.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Frank's answer is great and like he said, `data.table` has rolling join but `dplyr` does not. So I think `data.table` is a better choice here. However, if you want to stay in `dplyr`. Here is one idea.

```
library(dplyr)
df3 <- df %>%
  full_join(df2, by = c("e" = "o")) %>%
  mutate(Date_ABS_Diff = abs(d - d2)) %>%
  arrange(e, Date_ABS_Diff) %>%
  group_by(e) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  select(o = e, d2, a, newowner = p)
df3
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   o [4]
              o         d2       a newowner
          <chr>     <date>   <dbl>    <chr>
1 e3r@gmail.com 2017-02-02  600.50     Jeff
2   poi@aol.com 2017-04-28 3000.00      Sam
3 sdf@gmail.com 2017-05-05 4999.99     <NA>
4 tyu@gmail.com 2017-07-01 2050.60     Jeff
```

This approach uses `full_join` to combine all possible combination by email. After that, calculate the absolute difference between dates and use `arrange` and `slice` to select the record with minimum absolute dates.

Comment: Nice - I think this is where my mind would naturally go to, though I should learn more about rolling joins. What does slice do normally? I would have swapped slice with filter(!duplicated(e)) which would grab the first one after sorting ascending Date_ABS_Diff

Comment: @MattW. slice selects rows by position. Please see the documentation: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.3/topics/slice

Comment: Ah perfect. Thanks very much! Learned something new.

Answer (score 7):

This is a standard rolling update join in data.table:

```
library(data.table)
DT = data.table(df)
DT2 = data.table(df2)
DT2[DT, on=.(o = e, d2 = d), roll=-Inf, v := i.p ]

               o         d2       a    v
1: e3r@gmail.com 2017-02-02  600.50 Jeff
2:   poi@aol.com 2017-04-28 3000.00  Sam
3: sdf@gmail.com 2017-05-05 4999.99   NA
4: tyu@gmail.com 2017-07-01 2050.60 Jeff
```

If, per the title, you want the nearest match, use `roll = "nearest"` instead of `roll = -Inf`.

Dplyr doesn't have rolling joins and will never have update joins, so there's no analogue there.

Comment: thanks very much Frank! I remember learning about rolling joins in the past with data.table but I gravitated towards dplyr because it was easier to learn. I'll implement this and let you know how it goes! - Quick Q: is the -Inf call out the closest? or does it look for the closest from one side, earlier or later?

Comment: I have one other request. When I'm looking at these, I would like to do date closest to, meaning absolute value of distance to date. Can be past or future from date. How would I adjust the roll argument to match that?

Comment: @MattW In `?data.table`, the values for the `roll=` argument are documented. I think `roll="nearest"` will do what you're after.